# Заполнить двумерный массив целыми не повторяющимися числами

Tags: c#

Необходимо заполнить двумерный массив целыми не повторяющимися числами, как проверить на то что числа целые я проверил, а вот с проверкой встречается ли вводимый элемент не могу, есть ли способ проще чем еще один перебор всех элементов

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[,] Data = new int[x, y];
            int i,j,m,n;
            for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < y; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Введите элемент массива [" + i + ","+j+"]:");
                    int z = 0;
                    string input_data = Console.ReadLine();
                    bool success_data = false;
                    while (success_data == false)
                        if (Int32.TryParse(input_data, out z))
                        {
                            Data[i, j] = z;
                            success_data = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Некорректный ввод, введите корректное значение");
                            input_data = Console.ReadLine();
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Если не принципиально использовать именно двумерный массив, то можно использовать массив массивов, с которым проще работать, но инициализировать чуть сложней. Например по первым индексам проходиться через `foreach`, в котором искать например по [Array.Find](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.array.find)

Comment: Каков диапазон значений?

Comment: по условию все действительные числа, но думаю достаточно всего Int32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте хэшсет `var existValues = new HashSet<int>(x*y)`. Перед добавлением проверяйте (`Contains(z)`) есть ли значение уже в хэшсете, если нет --- добавляйте в хэшсет (`.Add(z)`) и массив, если есть --- запрашиваете новое.
Это вариант, как вы хотели, без перебора массива, но с приблизительно двойным расходом памяти.